# Не компилируется код с использованием библиотеки qt5. Помогите найти ошибку

Tags: c++, qt5

При копилировании кидает ошибку

```
CMakeFiles/qthelloworld.dir/MyDialog.cpp.o: In function `MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget*)':
/home/ilia/CLionProjects/qthelloworld/qthelloworld/MyDialog.cpp:7: undefined reference to `vtable for MyDialog'
/home/ilia/CLionProjects/qthelloworld/qthelloworld/MyDialog.cpp:7: undefined reference to `vtable for MyDialog'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/qthelloworld.dir/build.make:101: recipe for target 'qthelloworld' failed
make[3]: *** [qthelloworld] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/qthelloworld.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/qthelloworld.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:84: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/qthelloworld.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/qthelloworld.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'qthelloworld' failed
make: *** [qthelloworld] Error 2
```

Пытаюсь создать диалоговое окно с надписью "Hello World".

Вот главная функция

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "MyDialog.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyDialog *dialog = new MyDialog;
    dialog->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

В оригинальном коде обратных слэшей в импорте нет, вставил, чтобы показать сами импорты (мб в них дело).

Файл MyDialog.h

```
#ifndef QTHELLOWORLD_MYDIALOG_H
#define QTHELLOWORLD_MYDIALOG_H

#include <QtWidgets/QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QDialog>

class MyDialog: public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

};
#endif //QTHELLOWORLD_MYDIALOG_H
```

MyDialog.cpp

```
#include "MyDialog.h"

MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent) {
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    QLabel *lable = new QLabel(this);
    lable->setText("<font color = green> Hello, World! </font>");
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this);
    button->setText("close");
    layout->addWidget(lable);
    layout->addWidget(button);
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));
}
```

Буду благодарен, если скажете, в чем здесь ошибка, почему это не компилируется.

Comment: Вопрос часто задается. Стандартный ответ: перезапустить `qmake`.

Comment: @AnT, да, вот только qmake не используется (если я правильно понимаю, что есть qmake)

Comment: Очистить весь мусор, особенно moc-файлы и попробовать снова

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите CMakeLists.txt вашего проекта. Возможно не установлено автоматическое использование moc-генератора:
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

данная опция позволяет обойтись без ручного определения нахождения сгенерированных moc-файлов (как рекомендовано в другом ответе):

```
file( GLOB MOC_HEADERS src/*.hpp )
qt5_wrap_cpp( GUI_MOC ${MOC_HEADERS} )
```

и без прописывания ${GUI_MOC} в add_executable

Подробнее можно почитать тут: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-qt.7.html#manual:cmake-qt(7)

Там же есть и про аналогичные опции для UIC и RCC

Answer (score 1):

Все кто пишет на qt с cmake первое время тратят на данную ошибку Nое время. Для того что бы все запускалось с qt вам необходимо в свой cmake добавить следующие поля.

```
find_package( Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED )
aux_source_directory( src GUI_SOURCES )
file( GLOB MOC_HEADERS src/*.hpp )
qt5_wrap_cpp( GUI_MOC ${MOC_HEADERS} )
file( GLOB UIS_FILES ui/*.ui )
qt5_wrap_ui( GUI_UI ${UIS_FILES} )
```

Написал только для своего компонента для вашего случая компоненты можете посмотреть в документации.

Так же не забудьте добавить в executable:

```
add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${app_flags} ${GUI_SOURCES} ${GUI_MOC} ${UIS_FILES} )
```

В таргет линковщика так же нужно внести компоненты которые используются в вашем коде.

```
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Gui)
```